# Strange result from Fast Fourier transform signal reconstruction

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, non-linear-regression, dft

I have some data which is shown in the below figure and am interested in finding some of its Fourier series coefficients.

```
r = np.array([119.80601628, 119.84629291, 119.85290735, 119.45778804,
   115.64497439, 105.58519852, 100.72765819, 100.04327702,
   100.08590518, 100.35824977, 101.58424993, 105.47976376,
   112.27556007, 117.07679226, 118.99998888, 119.60458086,
   119.78624424, 119.83022022, 119.36116943, 115.72323767,
   106.58946834, 101.19479124, 100.11537349, 100.13313755,
   100.41846106, 101.42255377, 104.33650237, 109.73625492,
   115.14763728, 118.24665037, 119.35359999, 119.68061835])

z = np.array([-411.42980545, -384.98596279, -358.13032372, -330.89578468,
   -303.39129113, -275.76248957, -248.24478443, -221.07069838,
   -194.33260984, -168.05271807, -142.19357982, -116.62090103,
    -91.15354178,  -65.56745626,  -39.65284757,  -13.29632162,
     13.54374939,   40.84929432,   68.50496394,   96.33720787,
    124.08525182,  151.36802193,  177.98791952,  204.0805317 ,
    229.85399128,  255.44727674,  281.02166554,  306.75399703,
    332.74638285,  359.05528646,  385.74336711,  412.8189858 ])

plt.plot(z, r, label='data')
plt.legend()
```

[image]
Then I calculate the average sampling period, since it is not constant as seen in the Z variable:

```
l = []
for i in range(32-1):
    l.append(z[i]-z[i+1])
Ts = np.mean(l)
```

Then I calculate the fft:
    from scipy.fftpack import fft

```
rf = scipy.fftpack.fft(r)
```

For reconstruction of the signal then:

```
fs = 1/Ts

amp = np.abs(rf)/r.shape[0]
n = r.shape[0]
s = 0
for i in range(n//2):

    phi = np.angle(rf[i], deg=False)
    a   = amp[i]
    k   = i*fs/n

    s += a*np.cos(2*np.pi*k  *(z)  +phi)

plt.plot(z, s, label='fft result')
plt.plot(z, r, label='data')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

The result is strange however both in terms of amplitude and frequency.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sparks The question is what is the mistake in my code that gives the strange result.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the business process here, what are your expected results? what is a normal result?

Comment: @sparks Expected result: The reconstructed signal from the fast Fourier transform has almost the same amplitudes and frequency components as that of the original signal. The result I have obtained: The the reconstruction amplitude(blue color curve) is not the same as the original signal ampletude(orange color curve). Also the frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

The complex spectrum is a symmetric spectrum with the range of (-fMax/2, ..., +fMax/2).
You only used the right hand positive part of the spectrum. This means, your reconstructed signal contains only half of the spectrums frequencies.
Because the spectrum is symmetric, all you have to do is to double the calculated absolute values. However, there is an important exception. The DC value amplitude[0] must not be doubled.